# Cancelling pendingRequests is not working for angularJS 1.7.2 version

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angular-promise, deferred

I am trying to cancel pending api calls when the same api's are called again. I have dropdown onChange of which I am making my api call, here api call taking a lot of time to return data so i am cancelling all previous calls which are in pendingRequest array and keeping only the latest triggered call. please go through my code below

in my controller

```
angular.forEach($http.pendingRequests,function(r){
        console.log(r.contractId);
        if (r.contractId && r.contractId !== selectedContract) {
           r.cancel.resolve('cancelled');
        }
 });
```

Here I am checking if the pending request is latest or not, by comparing current selected contract with pendingRequest array.

This is how I have written my service

```
getDashboardData:function(selectedContract) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var cancel  = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.loaderOn=true;
    var url = 'my_url_here';
  $http.get(url, {
        ignoreLoadingBar: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        cancel:cancel, //this is of type $q.defer();
        contractId:selectedContract // here i assigned contrract id just to delete all pending api's other than current
    }).then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
            $rootScope.loaderOn=false;      
    },function(error){
          console.log(error);
          return deferred.reject(err);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to cancel or reject pending api calls. Any help will be appreciated thank you. Let me know if any other info required. Please correct me here.

Comment: switchMap using rxjs will fix your problem

Comment: I am using angularJS not angular 2

Comment: sorry but i don't see that as a problem as i never used angularJS*. but afaik, rxjs is a util tool for your async needs, so there should be no problem installing a package for that

Comment: map in rxjs is does looping right? what is the difference of using angular foreacha and map?

Comment: map, yes its the same. map returns an array whilst forEach only traverses

Comment: I tried using _.map() from loadash.js, call are not getting cancelled.

Comment: ow my friend that's different. you have to use rxjs functionalities.  check this out https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-switchmap-example#switchMap

Comment: I understand friend, but i cant install new libraries in my project, more on i debugged my code, control is going inside the loop but resolve(), reject() are not working.

Comment: ok if you have no choice, will get back to you with regards to this. will have to read angularJS a little to verify my thoughts

Comment: Thank you so much, i will be waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and doubt if cancel property exist in config object of $http.get function. You can use timeout property and use the value for cancelling the existing request.

I have replaced cancel property with timeout.

I hope below code helps.

```
// Declare the below objects in service level not inside getDashboardData function 
var deferredObj = '';
var existingRequest = '';

getDashboardData: function(selectedContract) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

// Below condition will check to cancel the existing request
if (existingRequest) {
   existingRequest = '';
   deferredObj.resolve();
   deferredObj = '';
} else {
    deferredObj = $q.defer();
}
$rootScope.loaderOn=true;
var url = 'my_url_here';
existingRequest = $http.get(url, {
    ignoreLoadingBar: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    **timeout : deferredObj.promise**, //this is of type $q.defer();
    contractId:selectedContract // here i assigned contrract id just to delete all pending api's other than current
}).then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data.data);
        $rootScope.loaderOn=false;      
},function(error){
      console.log(error);
      return deferred.reject(err);
  });

return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Hi dev, yesterday i figured it out, yes you are right i was missing timeout, so it was taking default timeout hence it was not cancelling the call. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = new Map() // put this outside the main function

getDashboardData() { // call this on change
  const url = 'my_url_here';  // value should be constant
  const oldRequest = request.get(url) // get the last promise request 

  oldRequest.reject && oldRequest.reject('old request') // cancel's the last promise request
  // last promise request successCallback won't be called since the promise is already rejected

  $q((resolve, reject) => { // creates a new promise
    request.set(url, { resolve, reject }) // store resolve, reject
    return $http.get(url) // create api request
  })
  .then(successCallback) // on request success
  .catch(rejectedOrErrorCallaback)
}
```

you can re implement it to something like this.
btw as per documentation. `$http.pendingRequests` is primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes. so i think that's a flag to stay away from using

Comment: if you have questions regarding my answer feel free to ask.

Comment: You have completely mis-understood my question.

Comment: edited my answer. I get what you wanted, what i'm giving you is an idea/somewhat answer. you should refactor your code to this or find a way to achieve something like this. FYI. api request to server won't be cancelled, it will succeed but won't be catched on successCallback if already rejected